# Call method once after viewDidLayoutSubviews

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need a little help to understand the `viewDidLAyoutSubviews`method and how to safely use it.

I need to edit some of my subviews programmatically before the `viewDidAppear` method. And in order for it to work properly I of course need to wait until the targeted subviews are layed out before I edit them.

Now I thought this was what the `viewDidLayoutSubviews`method was for, but when I tested it I found out that it was actually called two times before my `viewDidAppear` method. I tried to edit my subviews only the first time `viewDidLayoutSubviews` was called, because I just want to run `[self editMySubviews]` once, but then the targeted subview wasn't ready and it got messed up. This is how I tried:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    if (!myBoolean) {
        [self editMySubviews];
        myBoolean = YES;
    }
}
```

Of course if I remove the `if-statement` it fixes itself next time the method is called, but I only want `[self editMySubviews]`to be called once.

So my question is, when I can call the `[self editMySubviews]` method before the `viewDidAppear` method, and be 100% sure that all subviews are ready to be edited? Now in my case the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` gets called two times before `viewDidAppear`, but will that be the case every time? Is it safe to just call `[self editMySubviews]` after the second time `viewDidLayputSubviews` is called?

Comment: What are you doing in `editMySubviews`?

Comment: Editing some button constraints according to its superView.frame.size.width which is different on different devices

Comment: Then why do you need to do it just once?  You should do it every time the subviews layout incase the superview size changes.

Comment: Because I want to control when it gets called, I don't want it to get called every time a subview changes.

Comment: `viewDidLayoutSubviews` get called multiple time for a single change in layout you can't determine which call gives it correct result, so leave it as it is let it call multiple times there is no problem it.

Comment: if you really want it to only call once, you can use `dispatch_once`

Comment: ps. Remember to call `super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()`! Not what you were asking, but definitely a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment you said

## Editing some button constraints according to its superView.frame.size.width which is different on different devices

After viewdidload you will get the proper size from view.bounds
so you can easily set/update constraint and add at the end of this
setNeedsUpdateConstraints and layoutIfNeeded method call